# Output errors on advancved parameters panel

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I have no idea if the issue is regarding a update on php version on the server or some kind of attack I got in my store, but in my "advanced parameters" panel is outputting some errors, above I leave the information. Does anybody had some kind of similar issue?

```
PrestaShop™ 1.5.4.1



Verify Settings
Parameters required: OK
Optional parameters: Please fix the following errors
pdo_mysql

List of changed files

Changed/missing files have been detected.
Ficheiros em falta (6)
modules/blocknewsletter/mails/en/index.php
modules/blockwishlist/mails/en/index.php
modules/followup/mails/en/index.php
modules/mailalerts/mails/en/index.php
modules/referralprogram/mails/en/index.php
modules/sendtoafriend/mails/en/index.php



Ficheiros actualizados (64)
classes/controller/FrontController.php
modules/bankwire/bankwire.jpg
modules/bankwire/views/templates/hook/payment.tpl
modules/blocknewsletter/blocknewsletter.css
modules/blocknewsletter/blocknewsletter.php
modules/blocknewsletter/index.php
modules/blocknewsletter/controllers/index.php
modules/blocknewsletter/controllers/front/index.php
modules/blocknewsletter/controllers/front/verification.php
modules/blocknewsletter/img/index.php
modules/blocknewsletter/img/icon/index.php
modules/blocknewsletter/mails/index.php
modules/blocknewsletter/mails/en/newsletter_conf.html
modules/blocknewsletter/mails/en/newsletter_verif.html
modules/blocknewsletter/mails/en/newsletter_voucher.html
modules/blocknewsletter/translations/index.php
modules/blocknewsletter/views/index.php
modules/blocknewsletter/views/templates/index.php
modules/blocknewsletter/views/templates/front/index.php
modules/blocknewsletter/views/templates/front/verification_execution.tpl
modules/blocknewsletter/views/templates/hook/blocknewsletter.tpl
modules/blocknewsletter/views/templates/hook/index.php
modules/blockwishlist/mails/en/wishlink.html
modules/blockwishlist/mails/en/wishlist.html
modules/cashondelivery/cashondelivery.jpg
modules/cashondelivery/views/templates/hook/payment.tpl
modules/editorial/EditorialClass.php
modules/editorial/editorial.css
modules/editorial/editorial.php
modules/editorial/editorial.tpl
modules/editorial/index.php
modules/editorial/translations/index.php
modules/followup/mails/en/followup_1.html
modules/followup/mails/en/followup_2.html
modules/followup/mails/en/followup_3.html
modules/followup/mails/en/followup_4.html
modules/mailalerts/MailAlert.php
modules/mailalerts/index.php
modules/mailalerts/mailalerts-account.php
modules/mailalerts/mailalerts-ajax.php
modules/mailalerts/mailalerts-extra.php
modules/mailalerts/mailalerts.php
modules/mailalerts/controllers/index.php
modules/mailalerts/controllers/front/account.php
modules/mailalerts/controllers/front/actions.php
modules/mailalerts/controllers/front/index.php
modules/mailalerts/img/index.php
modules/mailalerts/mails/index.php
modules/mailalerts/mails/en/customer_qty.html
modules/mailalerts/mails/en/new_order.html
modules/mailalerts/mails/en/productcoverage.html
modules/mailalerts/mails/en/productoutofstock.html
modules/mailalerts/translations/index.php
modules/mailalerts/views/index.php
modules/mailalerts/views/templates/index.php
modules/mailalerts/views/templates/front/index.php
modules/mailalerts/views/templates/front/mailalerts-account.tpl
modules/mailalerts/views/templates/hook/index.php
modules/mailalerts/views/templates/hook/my-account.tpl
modules/mailalerts/views/templates/hook/product.tpl
modules/referralprogram/mails/en/referralprogram-congratulations.html
modules/referralprogram/mails/en/referralprogram-invitation.html
modules/referralprogram/mails/en/referralprogram-voucher.html
modules/sendtoafriend/mails/en/send_to_a_friend.html
```

Comment: What's are the problems specifically? Do you have some errors in the backoffice? Frontoffice?

Comment: Changing index.php is a security issue, which is its content?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if _PS_DEBUG_PROFILING_ is enabled on your store. You can check the same in the following file on your store:

/config/defines.inc.php

Search for _PS_DEBUG_PROFILING_ and see if the value for it is 'true' or 'false'

It should be 'false', change it if it is not and see if the problem is solved.